# Fourth order non-constant-coefficients ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, special-functions, nonlinear-system, airy-functions

I want to solve the following fourth-order differential equation in $G(x)$:
$$
G^{(IV)}(x)=p(x)G(x)
$$
If $p(x)=C\in\mathbb{R}$, the answer is a linear combinations of $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ and $e^{\pm x}$. For general $p(x)$ I do not know.

I would be in particular interested in the cases of $p(x)$ being $p(x)=x^\chi$ or $p(x)=x^\chi e^{-x^2}$, with $\chi\ge 0$.

I thought about a WKB or Modified Airy Function approach, but I do not see a clear path.

Comment: There may be a general power series solution if $p(x)$ can be represented as such. But really, it depends on the boundary conditions as well as the practical application for the answer. On finite interval you can use Fourier series, or generalized Fourier series. If you can guess a likely solution shape, you can also use variation of parameters to get some kind of approximation...

Comment: For the $p(x)=x^\chi$ case, the solution can be written in terms of the hypergeometric PFQ function. Tack on the exponential, and it looks unsolvable exactly unless, as Yuriy suggested, you try the power series solution.